# Unexpected appearance of â in man

Tags: man, character-encoding

In few of the `man` pages I've often seen below typical appearance of the character `â` in stead of an apostrophe, say in `man who`,

```
-T, -w, --mesg 
add userâs message status as +, - or ?
```

Why would that happen? Anything with encoding?

How do I correct it?

I've been able to mimic it with appropriate changes, its local albeit and needs `./`,

```
man ./<corrected_page_name>
```

Any way to avoid using `./`?

It's,

```
GNU/Linux 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5
```

Comment: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: What terminal are you using? I mean, is this a Linux GUI desktop with the default Terminal type app, or are you logging in remotely? If the latter, then the problem is likely that your remote terminal app isn't set to expect UTF-8.

Comment: It's a remote VM without a GUI, I SSH it through PuTTY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The â is an artifact of using UTF-8 characters without handling them properly.  That's the first byte of multiple bytes in a UTF-8 character.  If the terminal is setup to know about UTF-8, it combines those bytes on the screen so you can read it.

You can fix this for PuTTY by setting the translation to UTF-8.

Further reading:

- [4.10.1 Controlling character set translation](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-charset) (PuTTY FAQ)
- [Configuring PuTTY to use UTF-8 character encoding](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/configuring-putty-to-use-utf-8.html)
- [How to fix PuTTY showing garbled characters?](https://serverfault.com/questions/475925/how-to-fix-putty-showing-garbled-characters)